# jquery hasClass "active" on ul#navigation li on page load not working

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("li").click(function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass("active") )

          $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); 

    });
});
```

I have a navigation bar made and am using this code to add a transparency effect on hover:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".thumbs").fadeTo("slow", 0.6); 

 $(".thumbs").hover(function(){

    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); 

    },function(){

    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.4); 

    });

});
```

I'm also using hoverIntent.

The opacity rollover works a treat, but I'd like my "active" page to  have 100% opacity, but I can't seem to get it to work..what am I doing wrong?

the link in questions HTML is:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li class="active"><a href="page.htm"></a></li>
</ul>
```

the nav works perfect minus my "active" class so I think I provided all the necessary code.

Comment: what are you saying is not working? the fadeto you have in the first jquery code section?

Comment: Sorry

The fade in/out works fine on hover. I would like any LI with a class of "active" to have its opacity 100%. I use php to determine what the page is, and then add an "active" class to the li. but the opacity doesn't get applied - does fadeTo only work on a hover?

Comment: maybe you need to rephrase your question, because no one knows what 'active' class is, unless you show it. so your problem is your class you're applying not working?

Comment: I was under the impression that the above jquery:

$(document).ready(function(){

$("li").click(function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass("active") )

          $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); 

    });
});

would look for any LI element with a class of "active" and then apply the fadeTo("slow", 1.0); event. 

is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the hasClass test. You can replace...

```
$("li").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("active") )
          $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); 
    });
});
```

with this.....

```
$("li.active").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), you probably want [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) here, but you can do it even simpler than that :)

On your page load you can just do this using the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$("li:not(.active)").fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
```

This will only fade out the `<li>` which **don't** have `class="active"`